# How to detect mouse interaction with Line (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

i want to execute an anonymous function when the mouse interacts with the Line. But the methods "setOnMousePressed", "setOnMouseClicked", "setOnMouseEntered", are not working.

```
        this.line = new Line();
        this.line.setStartX(10);
        this.line.setStartY(10);
        this.line.setEndX(20);
        this.line.setEndY(40);
        this.line.setStroke(Color.PINK);
        this.line.setStrokeWidth(5);
        this.line.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            System.out.println("test");
        });
```

If I understand correctly, this happens because the library does not consider a Shape as an interactive element, not having the necessary attributes for the "OnMouse..." methods to work. In my case I cannot use Canvas, how can I achieve this result?

Comment: In what specific way does it not work? There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so any errors must elsewhere. Create and post a [mre]. *"the library does not consider a Shape as an interactive element"*. This is not a true statement; mouse events are triggered by shapes.

Comment: exactly, i can't find the error. The console just doesn't print anything.

Comment: So create and post a [mre]. You can’t expect anyone to diagnose code that has nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

The example code from your question already works, just run it, put the mouse over the line, and look at the console.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(10);
        line.setStartY(10);
        line.setEndX(20);
        line.setEndY(40);
        line.setStroke(Color.PINK);
        line.setStrokeWidth(5);
        line.setOnMouseEntered(event -> System.out.println("test"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(line)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes agreed with the above comments and this proof of life example.
If I had to guess I would say you are experiencing a lack of interactivity because you have your lines in some layered set of nodes. Maybe in a series of groups that are together on a StackPane. If so then you probably have some other node/parent/group layered on top of the group that has your Line(s). This would intercept mouse and keyboard events.

The only other possibility would be if you had line.setMouseTransparent(true) set somewhere else, or the line's parent node/group had setMouseTransparent(true).